# How do I fix "Launch failed. Binary not found" and "'Launching project Debug' has encountered a problem. Error starting process" error messages?

Tags: eclipse

I am completely new to eclipse and c++. I've been doing some learning online and wanted to get an ide for c++, so I got eclipse and Cygwin gcc (I'm on Windows if that helps), but I haven't been able to make my code run. When I right click my project in eclipse, and click "Run as" then "2 Local C/C++ Application", I get a "Launch failed. Binary not found" error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxf4M.png)

When I press "Launch in 'Run' mode", I get a "Launching project1 Debug' has encountered a problem. Error starting process" error meeeage:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtXqj.png)

I get no errors in the compiler. I have tried cleaning and building the binary file. I have set the run configuration to the path of the file. I have added a bunch of environments that people have reccomended to do online. I have ticked the Cygwin PE Parser in the binary parsers. With each of my efforts, the error messages persist and I am losing hope. I would appreciate any help!